# Can't implement onInfoWindowClick in java for android google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm attempting to use onInfoWindowClick for an android app. I would like to be able to click the info window of a marker and have the user be redirected to an external website. I have searched throughout this site and have found similar questions, yet I haven't been able to implement any of them successfully.

Essentially, I'm trying to use this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows

Below is the code I have as of now. It is yielding an error on the last override, and on the "this" at the end of the middle block of code.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng atlanta = new LatLng(33.759258, -84.364265);
    Marker atlMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(atlanta).title("ATL").snippet(atlanta.toString()));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(atlanta, 10));
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker atlMarker) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.atlantaga.gov/"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

}